# linear layout in relative layout error

Tags: android, android-layout

I have relative layout and inside it there are two linear layouts

the program works without the first linear layout. can any one explain why ?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bngp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Cart"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Cart"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

---

//  this is the linear layout causes error

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/Cart"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Product"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:text="Product"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Quantity"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Quantity"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Price"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Value"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Value"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

// end of linear layout

---

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@id/table" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linear"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="Total Value: "
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Final_result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/linear"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

---

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/linear"
        style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Confirm" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Clear" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Possibly because you're missing `android:weightSum=""` in the first `LinearLayout`, you're defining `android:layout_weight` in it's children

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Other than `heights` or `widths` of views not being set and some "best practices" not addressed it seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Check your layout now. I have edited some lines. use @+id instead of @id. You must know the difference between @id , @+id and @android:id.

ie,

```
"@android:id" which means you are referencing an item in Android namespace.

"@id" means you have defined ids in your application itself,
```

eg:-

===========================================================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <item name="TextView1" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

in this case you have defined a textview id in your resources. Now you can use ,

```
<TextView
    android:id="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

===========================================================

```
"@+id" means you are created a view (textview , layouts , etc..) in your layout and you wanted to add the id to R.java.
```

Check your layout now,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bngp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Cart"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="Cart"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Cart"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:text="Product"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Price"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Value"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/table" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linear"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:text="Total Value: "
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Final_result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Confirm" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Clear" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, instead of using @id/blah, always use @+id/blah (even if you are not defining the view). It doesn't hurt, and can prevent some really hard to track down errors.

For more details, please provide the error you are receiving.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer. 
It is true a + is required for a new id. Otherwise, the builder might assume the id already exists in the Ressource folder R.java , or link it to an already existing resource you didn't necessarily want to use

Downvotes should be justified and edited up to a certain level smh...